# How do I get selection field value in odoo?

Tags: python, selection, odoo-12

I have a `selection field` on a model called `hr.overtime.rule` like this:

`buttons = fields.Selection([('per_day', 'Per Day'), ('monthly', 'Monthly')])`

Now I have another model which, based on selected value it should do some computations. The logic is that when it is `per_day` it should do different computations and when in `monthly` it should do again different computations and that's why I need to check with an `if statement` whether is `per_day` or `monthly`.

### What have I tried:

- Imported the class to my current working python code: `from .hr_attendance_policy import hr_overtime_rule`  then I checked the value like this: `value = hr_overtime_rule.buttons`. It works to an extended way, it is just stuck at only one value: `monthly`
- Made a `Many2one` relation field: `button_id = fields.Many2one('hr.overtime.rule')`
  it works if you do `if not` or `if` but I specifically want either `per_day` or `monthly`

Thanks for your time fellas! I'd really appreciate your thoughts into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is performing computations based on the value of a specific field, in this case, what I can suggest is to use an onchange function on that field:

example:

```
#better rename to hr_overtime_rule_id
button_id = fields.Many2one('hr.overtime.rule')

@api.onchange('button_id')
def onchange_button_id(self):
    if self.button_id.buttons == 'per_day':
        computations1()
    if self.button_id.buttons == 'monthly':
        computations2()
```

make sure your field grabs the object, otherwise you may need to define a new One2many field in the original model to link it with the current model using the reverse keyword

Comment: Thank you on the answer. I believe this is what I was looking for, just I have to specify that computations happen on another model. Idk if I'm clear enough.

Comment: I have edited the answer to solve your problem, if it does, please mark it solution, Thanks

Comment: Alright. I will see.

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution and quite fairly gets the job done! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of selected field you can also do this:

1. Find a relation of your current working model and the other model.
2. After finding the relation(or just create one) you can access it with a related field
3. The syntax should be smth like this: `var = fields.Many2one('your.model')` and then `var2 = fields.Selection(related='var.technical_name')`

and after doing so, you can check it with `if statements`